# How to hide an HTML checkbox but still show its label

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, jquery-ui-selectable

I'm new to jQuery and I have been trying to figure out how to use the jQuery-ui Selectable component as an alternative to a set of checkboxes.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/

I think I could get it to work if I can find a way to hide the checkbox but still show its label. (I'm no HTML expert either). Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use the `selecting` and `unselecting` events for this, for example:

```
$( "#selectable" ).selectable({
    selecting: function(event, ui) {
        $(ui.selecting).find(':checkbox').attr('checked', true);
    },
    unselecting: function(event, ui) {
        $(ui.unselecting).find(':checkbox').attr('checked', false);
    }
});
```

[You can test it here, with the checkboxes visible to see it working](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/5mf5L/2/), and [here's that same version with just some added styling to hide the checkboxes](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/5mf5L/3/).

Though, if you're doing AJAX submissions, [check out the serialize demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/#serialize) that shows you can get any value derived from the elements, it need not be an actual input element.

Comment: Hi Nick, fantastic, that's exactly what I was looking to be able to do. Thanks very much.